# touchpad driver for dell latitude e5440 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad

The touchpad was working fine on windows 10, but now that I have installed ubuntu 18.04, it is too sensitive. Adjusting the mouse speed setting didn't work. Also the xset commands didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing similar issues. The best I could achieve is this:

Switching to libinput reduces the issues of disturbances and autoclicks while scrolling. See here https://linuxmint.com/rel_tara_cinnamon.php. One may need to do `apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hw` if can't install `apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

However, right click not responding frequently and cursor shakes at times are problems which still remain. I discovered that cursor shakes when another finger comes close to touchpad without touching it, so keep the other fingers away to avoid this. For right click I use button and have also converted right Alt into a right click with the help of keyboard shortcuts and xdotool combined.

Sm1 has asked same question at [Bug touchpad Dell E5440 Mint 19](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=276130). Any more suggestions requested.

update: two perfect scrolling positions: 1- scrolling diagonally with fingers touched, 2- scrolling horizontally with fingers touched and also aligned in horizontal way

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It may be helpful if you edit your answer and add the instructions to switch to libinputs. Relying on external links can be a problem if the link ever goes down or is moved.